# undefined method `each' for "#<Complaigns::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000003cfb4c8>":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, called `Complaign`, with some other attributes along with the date of complaign (`c_date`).

In the `ComplaignController`, I have an `index` view, which displays all the `complaigns`. There is a filter which takes from date and to date. On filtering that, it works fine, and properly displays the complaigns fired on those dates.

Now I want the result of this query to be passed on to a different method, say export method.

I thought of passing this from the index view, since it is stored in `@complaigns`.

This is my index method:

```
def index
        if params[:from] && params[:to]
            from = params[:from].to_date
            to = params[:to].to_date
            @complaigns = Complaigns.where(:c_date => from..to)
        else    
      @complaigns = Complaigns.all
        end    
  end
```

In the index view, this is what I have written

```
<%= link_to "Export", {:controller => "complaigns", :action => "export", :complaigns => @complaigns}%>
```

This is the export method

```
def export
         @complaigns = params[:complaigns]
  end
```

Now, in the export view, when I do the follwing line:

`@complaigns.each`, I get this error--

```
undefined method `each' for "#<Complaign::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000003cfb4c8>":String
```

Now this is because, I think, there is no method `each` in `String` class. Is there any way, I can convert the String to Complaign type in the method `export` or while passing it from the index view, pass it as Complaign object instead of String? Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: It gives error in the index views itself now, the index view has such a call -- `@complaigns.each`, it says undefined method each for #<Compaligns:somehexcode>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass Ruby on Rails model objects directly in the controller parameters, you can pass their corresponding ids and then load the models from the database. HTTP / Ruby on Rails is stateless. If you always go to index before export, one way how to solve this might be:

```
<%= link_to "Export", {:controller => "complaigns", :action => "export", :complaigns => @complaigns.map(&:id)}%>

def export
         @complaigns = Complaigns.find(params[:complaigns])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @complaigs is passed as string instead of actual active_record relations object. You should calculate @camplaigs in export instead of sending them. Or you can pass array of ids

```
@complaigns.collect(&:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless protocol, which means each request is independent from the other (unless you use cookie or session). For your **export** method, it knows nothing about the result of **index** method unless you pass enough information to it. So a simple solution can be:

**index view**

```
<%= link_to "Export", {:controller => "complaigns", :action => "export", :from => params[:from], :to => params[:to] }%>
```

**export method**

```
def export
  if params[:from] && params[:to]
    from = params[:from].to_date
    to = params[:to].to_date
    @complaigns = Complaigns.where(:c_date => from..to)
  else    
    @complaigns = Complaigns.all
  end    
end
```

Here, the parameters for **index** is passed to **export**.

But this method is not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) enough. You can consider using **index** for export like this:

```
def index
  if params[:from] && params[:to]
    from = params[:from].to_date
    to = params[:to].to_date
    @complaigns = Complaigns.where(:c_date => from..to)
  else    
    @complaigns = Complaigns.all
  end
  if params[:export].present?
     render 'export'
  else
     render 'index'
  end
end
```

Then in your *export* link, you can use this:

```
<%= link_to "Export", {:controller => "complaigns", :action => "index", :from => params[:from], :to => params[:to], :export => true }%>
```

*PS. These codes are not tested. Just for demonstration purpose.*

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are trying to do. The problem is that when the view is rendered, the resulting HTML is text, and therefore @complaigns is turned into it's equivalent text (the same as @complaigns.to_s).

To do what you want, you need to pass to your link, the same paramaters you used to create @camplaigns in your index view. So:

Change your link to:

```
<%= link_to "Export", {:controller => "complaigns", :action => "export", :to => params[:to], :from => params[:from]}%>
```

And then change your export method to:

```
def export
  index
end
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm trying now. But is that not equivalent to repeating the same query again and again?

Comment: Yes you are repeating the query, but take a look at caching techniques. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html or  http://www.nateberkopec.com/2015/07/15/the-complete-guide-to-rails-caching.html